# Any fast method to cast a numpy array to a custom class?

Tags: python, arrays, oop, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape (1000, 20) where a row is has 19 float values (`feature`) and one last value is a binary value (`label`).

The custom class is:

```
class Point(object):
    feature = None
    label = None

    def __init__(self, feature, label):
        self.feature = feature
        self.label = label

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} {1} labelled {2}".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.feature, self.label)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{0}({1}, {2})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.feature, self.label)
```

Is there a way can just pass the matrix and all rows can be converted to `Point` object? Or should I just iterate through each row?

For iterative solution I used this function:

```
def to_data_point(matrix):
    new_data = []
    for row in matrix:
        feature = row[:-1]
        label = row[-1]
        new_data.append(Point(feature, label))
    return new_data
```

Comment: I don't think you can really do much better than a for loop if you're converting to an arbitrary Python class. Do you really need the custom Point class? It would probably be better performance-wise to simply store your labels and features in separate numpy arrays.

Comment: Start with the iteration to show us clearly what you want.  It will be easier to suggest improvements if we have a working example to test.

Comment: What is `self.feature` supposed to be?  One of those 19 `feature` values, or all of them in some sort of list or array?  In other words, one `Point` object per row, or 19?  Also what is the `dtype` of the matrix?

Comment: @hpaulj Hi, sorry for the late reply. I added the function that I was using to convert the array/matrix to a list of objects. Yes, the 19 values are the features and last on is the label.